# Exception behaviour for Task depends on `async` keyword

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception

I have the following scenario:

Component A provides an interface `IMyInterface` and a registration mechanism for other components to register their implementors.

The interface looks like:

```
public interface IMyInterface 
{
    Task DoSomethingAsync(Context context);
}
```

In component A I want to start the method on for all implementors "in parallel" and then await the tasks.
The implementors may throw exceptions in their implementation (in my concrete scenario, IO is involved and I expect IOExceptions to occur from time to time; component A makes sure to catch the exceptions correctly...).

The code looks like the following

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var impl in implementors)
{
    var context = ...;
    tasks.Add(impl.DoSomethingAsync(context));   
}

// now do something different that takes some time

try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // swallow. we handle the exceptions for each task below.
}

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    if (task.IsFaulted)
        // log, recover, etc...
}
```

So here is my problem:
Since I am *not* using `await` for the single tasks, the exception behaviour depends on the way the implementor "creates" the returned `Task`.

```
public class Implementor1 : IMyInterface
{
    public async Task DoSomethingAsync(Context context)
    {
        // no awaits used in code here! 
        throw new Exception("oh the humanity");
    }
}

public class Implementor2 : IMyInterface
{
    public Task DoSomethingAsync(Context context)
    {
        throw new Exception("oh the humanity");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

(note the difference: the first implementor used the `async` keyword.)

When calling `DoSomethingAsync` on implementor 1, no exception is thrown in component A. The task object is set to 'faulted' and I can retrieve the exception from the Task. -> as I expected.

When calling `DoSomethingAsync` on implementor 2, an exception is immediately thrown. -> *not* what I want.

**So here's the question**:
How can I handle such situations to always observe behaviour 1? I have no control over how the authors of other components implement my interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU you can't modify the implementation of the interfaces and yet you'd like to have consistent exception handling strategy.

Well, you can wrap the call in another async method.

```
private async Task DoSomethingAsync(IMyInterface instance, Context context)
{
    await instance.DoSomethingAsync(context);
}
```

And call it as

```
foreach (var impl in implementors)
{
    var context = ...;
    tasks.Add(DoSomethingAsync(impl, context));   
}
```

This way, exception will not be propagated immediately instead wrapped in a `Task` and returned by async method.

To make it even more nicer you can create a [Decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and implement the method as `async` there. Then decorate all other implementations with your decorator before calling the method.

On the other hand if you can modify the implementation, servy's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Clever idea, I like this one!
I just managed to break this down to just one line: 
            `tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => await impl.DoSomethingAsync(context)));`

Comment: @cpt.jazz: I don't think `Task.Run` is appropriate here; you're changing execution context to the thread pool and putting unnecessary pressure on it.

Comment: @Stephen: so, how could this be improved when I want to avoid the separate method?

Comment: @cpt.jazz: If you don't want to just call it directly (and catch the exception), and you don't want a separate method, then you'd have to use a lambda and call it inline. Unfortunately, I believe lambdas would require a cast to be called, making the syntax very awkward: `tasks.Add(((Func<Task>)(async () => await impl.DoSomethingAsync(context)))());`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a faulted `Task` rather than having the method itself throw an exception, you need to create a `Task`, mark it as faulted, and return it.

Using .NET 4.6 you can just write:

```
return Task.FromException(new Exception("oh the humanity"));
```

If you're using an earlier version of .NET you can use the following `FromException` implementation:

```
public static Task FromException(Exception e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    tcs.SetException(e);
    return tcs.Task;
}
public static Task<T> FromException<T>(Exception e)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    tcs.SetException(e);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but as I said, I am not in control how the authors of other components implement my interface. When they never use `await` the compiler suggests to remove the `async` keyword. Since implementations will most likely do IO: what if the author forgets to wrap the IOException in a `Task`? How can I write _robust_ code to handle such situations?

Comment: @cpt.jazz You catch the exception and return a task representing that exception.  Obviously you can't change their method, you change yours (if it already returned exactly what you wanted your method wouldn't need to do anything at all).

Comment: so you mean something like this: 
    foreach (var impl in implementors)
    {
        var context = ...;
        try
        {        
            tasks.Add(impl.DoSomethingAsync(context));   
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.FromException(e));
        }
    }

Comment: @cpt.jazz Sure, if that's what you want to do.